# Initialise a hash in perl

Tags: perl, initialization

Say I have a hash like this:

```
   $word_count{$file}{$word}++ if blah blah
```

My program finds the number of times a word provided by the user occurs in a given file. Sometimes the user will provide a word which will not occur any times. If I try to print the amount of times a word occurs + 1 I get an error saying use of uninitialized value in addition, use of uninitialized value in printf.

How can I initialize this since the word won't be in my hash?

Comment: it would be helpful if you showed the code that produces those two warnings

Comment: There are almost certainly better ways to do what you're trying to do, but without seeing your existing code, it's impossible to make suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print 1 + ($word_count{$file}{$word} || 0);
```